# normal startup "freezes" before loginscreen

Tags: graphics

I recently installed 15.10 besides W8, really happy with it as a new ubuntu user. Today I replaced a old casefan and used my vacuumcleaner for removinging dust in my PC. 
Starting up ubuntu left me with the purple screen with ubuntu logo in the middle no login.

I phoned my dear brother a experianced Ubuntu user, he made make some commands ctrl alt F1, ctrl alt F7 and Ctrl alt F8..

results were F1: no listed errors, F7: nothing and F8: black screen blinking cursor.My brothers conclusion was it was some graphical error.

However, in recovery mode I am able to login everything seems stretched tho.

[looking to my drivers it shows this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Joy.jpg)

[but looking to my computer settings it shows this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iaqds.jpg)

My graphic card seems to be running (fan) connections seem to be fine aswel, Any clues or idears?

thanks,

J.

Answer (score 0):

The first Link is supposed to show my graphic card drivers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, It turns out Ubuntu does not apply mirror displays setting before logging in, my tv is connected to the computer (HDMI) so my main screen with login frame was out there.... all I needed to do was type my password and press ENTER. After logging in it remains mirrored after restart it extends..